# Which types of strain tensor are positive definite?

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

I am taking a look at different types of strain tensor. Specifically, I am thinking about if the infinitesimal strain tensor
\begin{align*}
\epsilon_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i})
\end{align*}
is positive-definite. I have Google searched some resources, and one of them says it is positive-definite. However, I think that it is not always positive-definite, as in the one-dimensional trivial case, if $\partial u/\partial x$ is negative, then it will not be positive-definite. Other sources say that other strain tensors, like the Lagrangian strain tensor, are positive-definite. I am not sure which types of strain tensor are positive-definite and also the implications if so. (I am thinking about the strain surface being an ellipsoid or not.) Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect sloppy terminology is used. Often is just matters whether or not it is indefinite or not. I suspect they mean to say "positive semi-definite or negative semi-definite".

Comment: @MikaelÖhman But is it possible for a quadratic form of the infinitesimal strain tensor to be negative?

Comment: Yes I don't see why not. It can also be zero. But it will not be indefinite. I don't know what materials you have been reading, a quick googling I didn't find much that talked about this (mostly just for deformationgradients, stretch and rotation tensors, where it matters.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Thanks. I can’t upvote due to inadequate reputation though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the material you found is just wrong. A trivial counter example is zero displacement = zero strain, which is not positive definite.

Nor do I see where such a property would be particularly useful when calculating anything.
It's a different story when talking about the other tensors we deal with (such as the elasticity tensor), where it definitely is a important property.

Looking at reputable resources (wikipedia, https://www.continuummechanics.org/) i see no mention of such claims when they present different strain measures.

Answer (score 0):

The strain tensor does not have to be positive definite, as mentioned before.

On the other hand, you are asking what type of strain tensor are positive definite. A positive tensor would have positive principal strains. That implies a tensor where you have elongation in 3 different directions.